# Connecting to internet via phone on Linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, mobile-phone, tethering

I have a Sony Ericsson C702 phone with a flat fee internet subscription (GPRS/UMTS). I'd like to connect my Linux (Kubuntu 9.04) laptop to internet via this phone, using bluetooth (I also have a cable connection but that's propietary, doubt it'll work). How can I do this, preferably via GUI / NetworkManager / the BT applet that comes with KDE?

In Windows I use SE's PC suite software which works great, but is not available for Linux.

Comment: Please add the sony-ericsson tag (http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sony-ericsson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine with using your USB cable instead of Bluetooth, you can (this works on my K800i, assuming SE didn't remove this option) go to Connectivity Settings -> USB -> USB Internet. There select the data account you use to access internet from the phone and turn it on. Now your phone will work as a usb network adapter when you plug it in. I imagine NetworkManager should see it immediately, althought I configured in manually "the Debian way". The name of the interface was usb0 in my case.

This was by far the easiest way to configure it, you reuse your phones Internet settings so you don't have to input all these settings on your PC.

EDIT: Re. the Debian way, I added the following to /etc/network/interfaces

```
# Phone internet connection
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet dhcp
```

So dhcp worked fine for me.

Comment: I have connected the phone and usb0 shows up. I make a new connection for it in knetworkmanager (setting it to dhcp) but if I try to connect it will just keep running but not succeed. What can be wrong and what is "the debian way"? Networking in Linux freaks me out a bit

Comment: Hi, I use dhcp as well so I am not sure what didn't work with Network Manager. Worth trying to set up manually. Kubuntu should have very similar network stack as Debian.

Comment: Magically works now

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a guide for setting up bluetooth dialup at Ubuntu help site: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothDialup

Comment: But I'm not looking for dialup. My phone has a permanent "broadband" (or so they call it) internet connection

Comment: @Bart - You still need to "dial up" to initiate the connection

Comment: I don't think so, at least not in the way you mentioned. My internet settings in the phone do not have a phone number listed anywhere.

Comment: Admittedly I'm not an expert on this, but I think you do need to use dialup. The "dialup" here is really confusing concept. You're not actually dialling to any actual number of the ISP, rather you're "dialling up" to the phone's GPRS internet connection system. This is done by dialling to a special number that the phone interprets as an internal code (such as *99#). That's how I've always connected to the broadband internet on my phone, in fact even right now. It boggles the mind and feels gimmiky, sure, but that's ultramodern mobile broadband technology for you. :)

Comment: Ah, that number was filled in by default. I'll try it

Comment: It works, though not via bluetooth. I used the dialup interface that appears when using the USB cable

Comment: @Bart: Yup, the dialup part seems to be technically pretty much the same whether using bluetooth or USB cable. Just with bluetooth you'll have to do some extra wierd things in order for the the dialup system to be able to access the phone's dialup interface through bluetooth. I wish it was easier and could be done via Bluez graphical interface - maybe some day.

Answer (score 1):

The USB cable you have is not propietary, your phone will show up as a normal USB CDC WMC device, with two serial ports available, /dev/ttyACM0 and /dev/ttyACM1. Those ports should can be used for normal dial-up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Arch Linux with KDE but it should also work for you: Use Blueman (an alternative Bluetooth Applet/Manager which is way better, than the buildin) ot connect your phone Dial-In Bluetooth port to and rfcomm device and use wvdial (or in my case: pywvdial) to dial in.

For details (lie wvdial configuration for your provider) you need to google ;)

Comment: I have installed blueman but cannot connect. I can add the phone to the list of devices, but I try to use it as network access point, it'll say "Connecting" for a while, then fail.

Comment: Ok, so I managed to get a "Success!" when connecting to the network access point (by first connecting to serial) but then how do I connect to the network? I don't get an extra interface or something.